# How can I convert a date to a UNIX timestamp with Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

I need to convert a date to a UNIX timestamp in a [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) template:

```
 <li>{{ user.expired }}</li>
```

Is there a function in Twig to do it?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There is the [built-in `date` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html) in Twig. You can pass any [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)-compatible argument.

```
 <li>{{ user.expired | date('U') }}</li>
```

`U` is the pattern that will display the unix timestamp.